# What are the correct permissions for enabling directory browsing in IIS?

Tags: iis-7, windows-8.1, file-permissions

My question is how do i set the right permissions to allow me to enable the directory browsing for a website I have on IIS. When click the browse website I get this screen:

I think I have the port set at 80 which was the default I think when I created the website.

So the instructions on the 403 error page read that I should allow for directory browsing. When I open up the IIS manager and click the settings for enabling directory browsing I get this error:

I have allowed all users and accounts possible to have all permissions on the folder(xml test book prob) for the website. My question is how do enable the directory browsing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://i1072.photobucket.com/albums/w362/LAtaco420/directorybrowser_zpsuh7vmzzc.jpeg

Comment: http://i1072.photobucket.com/albums/w362/LAtaco420/weberror_zpsbspc7ffs.jpeg

Comment: users without a "10" reputation aren't allowed to post images wtf?

Comment: Spam prevention. You need to earn some credit befor you're allowed to post images.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. For me do worked after change web.config permission file, from one status readonly on all privileges allowed. Also you should be log in as administrator.

Comment: I fixed the error it was stupid really, I had to change all files from read only to not read only in order for the web.config file to be changed. I tried opening up the web.config file in notepad and changing the "false" value for the    <directoryBrowse enabled="false /> to true and that's when I got the this file is read only and I was like oh duh lol. Thanks a lot .